# How to properly connect to an Azure MySQL database with FastAPI

Tags: python, azure, ssl, fastapi

I am trying to connect to my MySQL Azure database with my endpoint written in `FastAPI`. The connection is working when I run my connection method alone, but once integrated in the endpoint, I get an error:

```
 Failed to connect to the database: (mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError) 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'cluster_name.mysql.database.azure.com:port', system error: 1 [SSL: NO_CIPHERS_AVAILABLE] no ciphers available (_ssl.c:1006)
```

My code that connects to the database looks like this:

```
def create_db_engine():
    try:
        # Format the connection string
        connection_string = f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{password}@{host}/{database}"
        ssl_args = {'ssl_ca': "DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem"}

        # Create the SQLAlchemy engine
        engine = create_engine(connection_string, connect_args=ssl_args)

        # Test the connection
        connection = engine.connect()
        print("Successfully connected to the database.")
        connection.close()

        return engine

    except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
        print(f"Failed to connect to the database: {e}")
        return None

engine = create_db_engine()
#conn = engine.connect()
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
```

This method connects properly when I run it alone from python.
My API definition looks like this:

```
# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = db_init.SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


@app.post("/users/")
def create_user(user: schema.UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_user = crud.get_user_by_email(db, email=user.email)
    if db_user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Email already registered")
    return crud.create_user(db=db, user=user)


@app.post("/assistant_chat/")
def create_chat_message(chat_message: schema.ChatMessageCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return crud.create_chat_message(db=db, chat_message=chat_message)
```

When I run this server using uvicorn with uvicorn api:app --reload I get this error message Failed to connect to the database:

`(mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError) 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'cluster_name.mysql.database.azure.com:port', system error: 1 [SSL: NO_CIPHERS_AVAILABLE] no ciphers available (_ssl.c:1006)`

Comment: So I was trying out some more things and when I turn off the enforcement of SSL in Azure, it works perfectly fine. If anyone knows how to use it with SLL turned on, please let me know

Comment: 1. If you are running from your machine, `localhost` would not have SSL. The error could've been raised due to that.
2. Make sure that `localhost` (or your domain) is whitelisted in the Azure db instance.

Comment: I whitelisted the whole IP-space for testing, so this should not be the issue. What does your first point mean or how would I enable SSL on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with small changes I was able to connect **Azure MySql Database** with **SSL** Enabled.

Make sure to Install **mysql-connector-python**

**main.py** :

```py
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
import uvicorn
from . import app, database, crud, models, schemas

def get_db():
   db = database.SessionLocal()
   try:
       yield db
   finally:
       db.close()

@app.post("/users/")
def create_user(user: schemas.UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
   db_user = crud.get_user_by_email(db, email=user.email)
   if db_user:
       raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Email already registered")
   return crud.create_user(db=db, user=user)

@app.post("/assistant_chat/")
def create_chat_message(chat_message: schemas.ChatMessageCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
   return crud.create_chat_message(db=db, chat_message=chat_message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, log_level="info")
```

This is my connection code to connect **Azure Mysql database**

```py
# app/database.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "mysql+mysqlconnector://UserName:Password@HostName:port/databaseName"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, 
    connect_args={"ssl_ca": "DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt(1).pem"}
)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

I ran this using **uvicorn** with the following command:

```
uvicorn app.main:app --reload
```

I got below Ouput :
[image]

And successfully upload Data:
[image]

This my Schema Output :
[image]